# Converting fl in hexadecimal in c++

Tags: c++, floating-point, hex

I am new to C++, and programming, and I want to write a C++ program to convert a float in hexadecimal with the help of pointers

I've looked on other threads and really tried to get a hold of this but can't seem to figure it out. 
Here is what I have done so far:

```
int main()
{
    float number = -12.0
    unsigned char *ptr = ((unsigned char*) &number);

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(float); i++)
    {
        cout << "Byte "  [i] << "is : " << ptr[i] << endl;
    }
```

So with this, i assume I am able to have access to the bytes that compose the float.  However, can you suggest any ideas to convert this to hexadecimal. I guess, I have to be able to read the binary behind all this... but I am not really sure how. 

***Note:*** I understand how to convert from binary to hexadecimal

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex

Answer (score 0):

iostreams can print numbers in hexadecimal:

```
int main() {

float number=-1.0;

unsigned char *ptr = ((unsigned char*)&number);

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(float); i++)
{
    cout << "Byte ";
    cout << setw(0) << dec << i << "is : ";
    cout << setw(2) << setfill('0') << hex << ptr[i] << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

what you want might be sth like this:

```
float number=-1.0;
char cz[]="0123456789ABCDEF";
int si=sizeof(float);
char* ptr=(char*)(&number);
for(int i=0;si-i;++i){
    std::cout<<cz[((*ptr)&0xf0)>>4]<<cz[(*ptr)&0x0f]<<' ';
    ++ptr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have minor bug here `cout << "Byte "  [i]` which is the same as doing:

```
const char *text = "Byte ";
cout << text[i]
```

Another minor bug is that `ptr[]` is `char` thus `cout` treats it as a printable character (not a number), using `(int)ptr[i]` will do. Also you want print `i` as decimal and `ptr[i]` as hex, so you have to use [`std::dec`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/dec/) and [`std::hex`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/hex/)

```
cout << "Byte " << std::dec << i << " is : " << std::hex << (int)ptr[i] << endl;
```

You may polish it a bit by using [`std::setw()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setw/) and [`std::setfill()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setfill/) from `<iomanip>`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    float number = -1.0;
    unsigned char *ptr = ((unsigned char*) &number);

    cout << std::setfill('0');

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(float); i++)
    {
        cout << "Byte " 
             << std::dec << std::setw(0) << i << " is : " 
             << std::hex << std::setw(2) << (int)ptr[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This will print out:

```
Byte 0 is : 00
Byte 1 is : 00
Byte 2 is : 80
Byte 3 is : bf
```